# Make <: ... :> acts like one macro

Tags: active-characters

I use `jinja` to write templates. This makes me work with files like the one below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\devtool[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

$f(x) = <:f:>$ .

\end{document}
```

To test my templates before using it, I would like that `<:f:>` works like `\devtool{f}`.

In other words, I would like to activate the sequences `<: ... :>` to be similar to `\devtool{...}`.

Comment: This can be done with active characters or (with fewer side effects) using the `process_input_buffer` callback in LuaTeX, but still... wouldn’t it be easier to just use your editor to string replace `<:` by `\devtool{` and `:>` by `}` in each document?

Comment: @Gaussler No I need to keep a polluted LaTeX file. This is my workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard procedure is to make `<` math active and give it a suitable definition:

- if `:` follows, look up for `:>` and absorb everything in between, passing it to `\devtool`;
- otherwise, issue a standard “less than” symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\devtool[1]{\fbox{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\devtool@}{\@ifnextchar:{\devtool@@}{\stdless}}
\mathchardef\stdless=\mathcode`<

\begingroup\lccode`~=`< \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\devtool@

\def\devtool@@:#1:>{\devtool{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`<="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f(x) = <:f:>$

$1<2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why again is it that you need `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @Gaussler Defensive programming

Comment: @egreg I will play with this soon. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg Would it not be possible to use ligatures for this?

Comment: @Gaussler Ligatures are defined at the font level.